# Numpy giving error when not imported.

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

So I'm trying out machine learning, and following a tutorial I found online.

For some reason when I run my code numpy is giving me an error, even-though I am not importing that library. (I've been having problems with numpy)

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from sklearn import tree

#1 = smooth       0 = bumpy
features = [[140, 1], [130, 1], [150, 0], [170, 0]] #input
labels = ["apple", "apple", "orange", "orange"] #desired output
#0 = apple         1 = orange

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(features, labels)
print clf.predict([[160, 0]])
```

**Error:**

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c (python ^<C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\22\V
Ii532A.tmp)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 134, in <module
>
    from .base import clone
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 9, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module
>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module
>
    from .type_check import *
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <mod
ule>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 21, in <modu
le>
    from . import function_base
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\function_base.py", line 7, in <
module>
    from .numeric import (result_type, NaN, shares_memory, MAY_SHARE_BOUNDS,
ImportError: cannot import name shares_memory
shell returned 1
Hit any key to close this window...
```

Thanks

P.S.
Also looking for a couple tutorial suggestions, one with machine learning and NLP would be great

Comment: Scikit-learn requires the following dependencies, specified in their documentation: 
Python (>= 2.7 or >= 3.3),
NumPy (>= 1.8.2),
SciPy (>= 0.13.3).  http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html

Comment: I would say at least one of the modules you're using, imports numpy, so it is imported even if you don't write it explicitly in your code

Comment: @vipertherapper I have numpy 1.9.1 and SciPy 0.19.0

Comment: It's very likely your numpy/scipy install is broken or some of these are incompatible with each other (very common here when people are using windows). This is even more likely as you are not using painless approaches like using anaconda (python distribution).

Comment: @Stéphane Never knew modules could do that in python, thanks for the info

Comment: @Worker try adding `import numpy as np` to the top of your file.

Comment: @sascha Yeah, we use pip, I'll look into anaconda and possibly make a suggestion to use it, if we are allowed

Comment: pip and scipy is (currently) not a good idea on windows (but numpy should probably work)! (Gohlke's binaries can work; but care is needed)

Comment: @vipertherapper Tried it, getting the same error :(

Answer (score 1):

Numpy is a scikitlearn dependency. That means SKlearn is made on top of numpy.
Creating a virtualenv is a great idea so as to understand what the real issue is.

The same code worked for me and I can tell you the prediction is "orange". :P